# Why does this code print false in the last line

Tags: kotlin

```
fun main() {
    val names: HashSet<Person> = HashSet()

    val person = Person("AA", "BB")
    names.add(person)
    names.add(Person("FF", "JJ"))
    names.add(Person("KOK", "UHGU"))
    print(names)
    print(person in names)
    person.name = "TEST"
    print(names)
    print(person in names)
}

data class Person(var name: String, val surName: String)
```

I am trying to run the above code but the last statement ie print(person in names) is returning false.

If I change the declaration of the class person and make it class instead of data class, true is printed. Can someone help me understand why is this happening?

Changing the data class to class fixes the issue and true is printed. Can someone explain what's the reason of false print in case of data class.

Comment: I ran it both ways and got true both times.  The only difference in behavior is that data class has equals, hashCode, and toString generated automatically.  The class instance does not.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's because you're modifying the object after adding it to the set, in a way that affects how it compares to other objects. [From the Java docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html):

> Note: Great care must be exercised if mutable objects are used as set elements. **The behavior of a set is not specified if the value of an object is changed in a manner that affects equals comparisons while the object is an element in the set.** A special case of this prohibition is that it is not permissible for a set to contain itself as an element.

In this case, a data class has a `hashCode()` implementation based on the values of its constructor parameters (that's its "data"). When you add `person` to your `HashSet`, it's actually [being inserted into a `HashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html) using the *current hashcode value*. Then when you modify one of those constructor properties later, you're changing the hashcode that `person` returns - but the object is still stored in the set/map using the original hashcode as its key. So the `in` check fails, because there's no key matching the new hashcode.

Using a plain class works because you're not doing any equality / hashcode calculations based on your data (which is what a data class gives you for free) - so the hashcode doesn't change when you update `name`, and you're effectively just comparing object references (the default `hashCode` implementation for a class is usually [just the object's memory address](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode()), which will always match).